# Twig - Use variable key for object

Tags: php, twig

I am using Twig and I have a problem.

I have a problem when I want to use a variable index for an object.

Here is my code:

```
{% for label, field in params.fields %}
    {{ dump(data.field) }}
{% endfor %}
```

data is an object containing `{'email': 'test@test.fr', 'name': 'John'}`.

Field is an array of string containing `['email', 'name']`

I can't show the value my object dynamically.

**`{{ dump(data.email) }}`** works.

How can I use dynamic indexes?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Twig syntax, `data.field` is equal to `$data['field']` in PHP. In other words, Twig use `field` as the array key name instead of taking the value of the `field` variable and use it as a key name.

---

If you want something similar to `$data[$field]`, you can use the [`attribute()`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/functions/attribute.html) function:

> The `attribute` function can be used to access a "dynamic" attribute of a variable:

Example:

```
{{ dump(attribute(data, field)) }}
{# or simply #}
{{ attribute(data, field) }}
```