# Dynamic variable name TWIG

Tags: symfony, loops, twig, symfony-forms

I use symfony forms and i have serie of fields which have the same name + index number as follow:
in0, in1, in2, in3...

Is it possible to loop names in TWIG like:

```
{% for i in 0..10 %}
    {{ form_row(propForm."in"~i) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twig - Use variable key for object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38771754/twig-use-variable-key-for-object)

Comment: I think this post is more explicit than the duplicate link but you're right. It's related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [attribute](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html) function as example:

```
{{ form_row(attribute(propForm, ("in"~i) ) ) }}
```

PS: remember to use the parenthesis to generate the attribute name